# $\hat{x}(f_{n})\to\hat{x}(f)$ if $f_{n}\to f$, then $\hat{x}$ continuous.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Help me to prove this please:

Let $X$ be a separable Banach space and $\hat{x}\in X^{**}$. If for all converging sequence $f_{n}\to_{\sigma(X^{*},X)} f$ in $X^{*}$ we have $\hat{x}(f_{n})\to\hat{x}(f)$, then $\hat{x}\in X$.

Comment: Look at [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/296587/253273)

Comment: @A.Γ. But the hypotheses only say that $\hat{x}$ is $\sigma(X^{\ast},X)$-sequentially continuous. Since $\sigma(X^{\ast},X)$ isn't metrisable when $X$ is an infinite-dimensional Banach space, deducing the $\sigma(X^{\ast},X)$-continuity of $\hat{x}$ needs to be done.

Comment: @DanielFischer Then I misinterpret the question and took it granted from the separability of $X$. Perhaps it is sufficient that equicontinuous subsets  of $X^*$ are metrisable.

Comment: I've tracked the result down to what I believe to be the original one.
**Theorem** [Banach, *Théorie des Opérations Linéaires*, 
Subwencji Funduszu Kultury Narodowej, 1932, page 124] Let $X$ be a separable Banach space. A subspace $Z$ of $X^*$ is weak-* closed if and only if it is weak-* sequentially closed.

Comment: @A.Γ. that's precisely what i wanted. Thanks!

Comment: @Basti You can also look at [Krein-Smulian theorem](https://books.google.se/books?id=ix4P1e6AkeIC&lpg=PA161&ots=0RdPtd-jYv&dq=%22weak%20*%20sequentially%20continuous%22%20separable%20Banach&hl=sv&pg=PA159#v=onepage&q&f=false) and corollaries.

Comment: @Basti .. or even better [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1986-097-02/S0002-9939-1986-0835903-X/S0002-9939-1986-0835903-X.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Let $r>0,\ B^{*}:=\{f\in X^{*}:\|f\|\leq r\}$. By the Krein-Smulian theorem, $S:=\hat{x}^{-1}(\{0\})$ is weak-closed if we can prove that $S\cap B^{*}$ is weak-closed. Let $x^{*}$ be in the weak-closure of $S\cap B$. Then $x^{*}\in B^{*}$, but since $X$ is separable, $B^{*}$ is metrizable in the weak-topology and therefore (using the hypithesis on $\hat{x}$) $<\hat{x},x^{*}>=0$. So, $S$ is closed and $\hat{x}$ continuous.

Comment: To introduce $x^*$ is not really necessary. $S$ weak* closed iff $S\cap B^*$ is weak* closed, but $S\cap B^*$ is metrisable, hence, $S\cap B^*$ weak* closed iff $S\cap B^*$ weak* sequentially closed iff $S$ is weak* sequentially closed. The latter is assumed. The last iff is easy due to the fact that weak* convergent sequences are bounded.