# How to show that $\lambda\in V^{**}$ is in the image of $V$ iff it is weak-* continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis, dual-spaces, weak-topology

Let $V$ be a Banach space and define the inclusion $\iota: V\to V^{**}, v\mapsto \left(\iota(v): f\in V^{*}\mapsto f(v)\in\mathbb{R}\right)$. I already showed that $\iota$ is a linear isometry, that it is a homeomorphism onto its image if $V$ has the weak topology and $V^{**}$ has the weak-* topology, and that $\iota(V)$ is weak-* dense in $V^{**}$. Now I have to prove that if $\lambda\in V^{**}$ then $\lambda\in \iota(V)$ if and only if $\lambda:V^*\to\mathbb{R}$ is weak-* continuous. The “only if” part is immediate, however I seem to can’t wrap my head around the “if” part. Has anyone a hint? **Please hints only!**

Comment: The weak-$*$ topology is the coarsest topology such that ...?

Comment: @gerw ...such that for every $v\in V$ the map $f\in V^{*}\mapsto f(v)\in\mathbb{R}$ is continuous. However I can only see that this helps me with the “only if” part.

Comment: I think the word *coarsest* should be the key here. However, the arguments seems to be a little bit involved. I have to think about it.

Answer (score 2):

If $\lambda$ is weak-* continuous, then the set $\{f \in V^* : |\lambda(f)| < 1\}$ is a weak-* open neighborhood of 0.  Now there is a nice basis of open sets for the weak-* topology, which perhaps you know.  This will relate $\lambda$ to a finite number of elements $v_1, \dots, v_n \in V$.  By looking at how $\ker \lambda$ relates to $\ker \iota(v_i)$, you can show that $\lambda$ is some linear combination of the $\iota(v_i)$.

Credit to:

> [What is the topological dual of a dual space with the weak* topology?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296531/what-is-the-topological-dual-of-a-dual-space-with-the-weak-topology)