# Weak* topologies on $M(\mathbb{R}^n)$ generated by $C_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

The space of finite signed Radon measures $M(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with total variation norm can be identified as either the dual space of continuous functions that vanishes at infinity $C_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$ or continuous function with bounded supported $C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ in the uniform norm. However, do they induce the same weak* topology on $M(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Comment: They coincide on bounded subsets of $M(\mathbb{R}^d)$.

Comment: The statement about locally convex spaces in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/296587/1212137) will probably interest you.

Comment: As the answer linked in P. P. Tuong’s comment suggested, the two topologies are not the same since they give different dual spaces. However, because $C_c(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is uniformly dense in $C_0(\mathbb{R}^d)$, a standard $3\epsilon$-argument shows that the two topologies coincide on any bounded subset, as Onur Oktay’s comment mentioned.

Comment: The restrictions of the two topologies to the sets $B_r = \{\mu\in M(\mathbb{R}^d): \|\mu\|_{tv}\leq r \}$ are the same. They do not coincide on $M(\mathbb{R}^d)$.

Comment: @DavidGao Thank you very much. I see it now.

Comment: @OnurOktay Yes, sorry for my mistake.

Comment: For example, take $(t_n)\subset \mathbb{R}$, $t_n\to\infty$. Let $\mu_n = n\delta_{t_n}$. Then $\mu_n(g) = ng(t_n)\to 0$ for each $g\in C_c(\mathbb{R})$, but not for some $g\in C_0(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: @OnurOktay Great example. I was considering some conterexample of escaping to infinity but I didn't think of adding a factor of $n$ to make it work.