# Shorter proof for $T$ compact and $x_n \to x$ weaky then $Tx_n \to Tx$ strongly

Tags: functional-analysis

I proved that if $X,Y$ are Banach spaces and $T: X \to Y$ is compact and $x_n \to x$ weakly then $Tx_n \to Tx$ strongly. I am now wondering if there is a shorter proof?

Here is my proof:

Let $x_n \to x$ weakly. By [this result here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337103/a-linear-functional-between-banach-spaces-is-weakly-continuous-iff-norm-continuo) $T$ is norm-norm continuous if and only if it is weak-weak continuous. Hence $Tx_n \to Tx$ weakly.

Next note that because $x_n\to x$ weakly the sequence $x_n$ is bounded. Hence $S=\{x_n\}\cup \{x\}$ is bounded. Since $T$ is compact it follows that $Tx_n$ has a (norm) convergent subsequence. Let's call it $Tx_{n_k}$. Since strong convergence implies weak convergence,  $Tx_{n_k}$ converges weakly and since the weak topology is Hausdorff we use uniqueness of the limit to get that $Tx_{n_k}$ converges to $Tx$ weakly. Finally, since $Tx_n$ has the same limit in the weak topology and in the strong topology, $Tx_{n_k} \to Tx$ strongly.

The proof seems to long in general but I am particularly unhappy with using the result I link to. Any ideas how to make this proof neater?

Comment: But, you need to show (the whole sequence) $(Tx_n)$ converges to $Tx$.

Comment: @DavidMitra Thank you for the comment. Good point. It's not clear to me at the moment if I can fix this mistake or if I will have to rewrite the proof.

Comment: Use your argument to show that every subsequence of $(Tx_n)$ has a further subsequence that converges to $Tx$. This will suffice.

Comment: Your linked result isn't overpowered here. If you wish, you could just incorporate its proof in your argument. (Given $f\in X^*$, $f\circ T$ is in $X^*$, so $(f\circ T) x_n\rightarrow (f\circ T)(x)$. This implies $(Tx_n)$ converges weakly to $Tx$.)

Comment: @DavidMitra Thanks for the hint!