# If $T: X \to Y$ is norm-norm continuous then it is weak-weak continuous

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X,Y$ be normed linear spaces (or Banach spaces if necessary) and let $T: X \to Y$ be linear. We call $T$ norm-norm continuous if $X,Y$ are endowed with the norm topology and similarly, weak-weak continuous if $X,Y$ are endowed with the weak topology.

I am trying to show that if $T$ is norm norm continuous then it is weak-weak continuous. My idea was to use the sequential definition of continuity and to show that if $x_n \to x$ weakly then $Tx_n \to Tx$ weakly. That was easy enough but to complete my proof I would now have to show that this implies that $T$ is continuous and I can't seem to prove it. It would be easy if the topologies were the norm topologies but with both spaces carrying the weak topology I don't see how to proceed.

My question is: Is it true that if $T$ is linear and $x_n \to x$ weakly implies $Tx_n \to Tx$ weakly then $T$ is continuous? If yes, could someone please show me a proof, I can't seem to work it out.

Comment: Yes. See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5795/weak-sequential-continuity-of-linear-operators).

Comment: @DavidMitra This is very helpful to me, thank you.

Comment: My previous comment addressed the question in the post body. I assumed (probably incorrectly) that you were referring to norm-continuity. For the question in your title, you could show that if a net $(x_\alpha)$ converges weakly to $x$, then $(Tx_\alpha)$ converges weakly to $Tx$. Towards this end, note $y^*\circ T\in X^*$ if $y^*\in Y^*$ (I presume you already did this for sequences; the proof for nets is the same).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is of course true that norm-continuous linear maps are weakly continuous. This follows from the fact that the weak topology is the initial topology w.r.t. to all continuous linear functionals, i.e. $\sigma(Y,Y^*)$ is the coarsest topology on $Y$ such that all $f\in Y^*$ are continuous. Then, by abstract nonsense, a map $T:E \to (Y,\sigma(Y,Y^*))$ (where $E$ is an arbitrary topological space) is continuous if (and only if) all compositions $f\circ T$ are continuous. For $E=(X,\sigma(X,X^*))$ you have that continuity because $f\circ T$ is norm-continuous and hence $\sigma(X,X^*)$-continuous.

---

You should be very careful with your *sequential* proof (the weak topologies are not metrizable if the spaces are infinite dimensional). There are Banach spaces where the weakly convergent sequences are always norm-convergent, the space $\ell^1$ of absolutely summable sequences is the most prominent example of such *Schur-spaces*. This means that the identity $(\ell^1,\sigma(\ell^1,\ell^\infty)) \to (\ell^1,$norm-topology$)$ is sequentially continuous but NOT continuous.

Comment: You used a characterisation of initial topologies for the proof of the implication " norm-norm $\implies$ weak-weak ". Is this because for weak topologies on Banach spaces there is no closed-graph theorem? I asked a similar question (still no answer), trying to prove facts of this type for a more general setting (locally convex spaces): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2131594

Comment: This post answers the same question, using the closed graph theorem (for Banach spaces) only for the counterpart of the implication that you showed: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337103