# description of dual space of space of Radon measure equipped with topology of weak convergence

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb R)$ be the space of Radon measures, equipped with topology $\tau$ generated by the following "weak convergence":

$$
\mu_n \rightarrow \mu \quad \text{iff} \quad \int f \, d\mu_n \rightarrow \int f \, d\mu \quad 
$$
for all continuous function $f$ with quadratic growth: $|f(x)|\leq C(1+|x|^2)$ for some $C>0$. Let $\mathcal{M}_2(\mathbb R)$ be the subspace of $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb R)$ that contains all Radon measures with finite second moment.

**I would like to know if there is a description of the topological dual of $(\mathcal{M}(\mathbb R),\tau)$ and $(\mathcal{M}_2(\mathbb R),\tau)$.**

I know $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb R)$ is the dual of $C_0(\mathbb R)$, so we have
$$
(\mathcal{M}(\mathbb R),\sigma(\mathcal{M}(\mathbb R),C_0(\mathbb R)))^*=C_0(\mathbb R)
$$
where  $\sigma(\mathcal{M}(\mathbb R)$ is the weak star topology. It is also obvious that convergence $\tau$ implies convergence in the weak star topology. So I was hopping the dual of  dual of $(\mathcal{M}(\mathbb R),\tau)$ or $(\mathcal{M}_2(\mathbb R),\tau)$ would just be the family of continuous functions wit quadratic growth.

I also notice that $\tau$ convergence is the same as convergence in Wasserstein 2 distance, when restricted to probability measures with finite second moment. I will also be interested to see if there is any connection.

I hope my question makes sense and looking forward to any hints and ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if $V$ is a vector space, $W$ is a vector space of functionals on $V$, and we give $V$ the weak topology with respect to $W$, then the topological dual of $V$ will be just $W$.  The proof is pretty much exactly the same as the case of the weak* topology, which you seem to be familiar with.   See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301745/an-explicit-construction-for-a-doubly-weak-topology/301774#301774) for more details.

So, in your case, the dual of either $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R})$ or $\mathcal{M}_2(\mathbb{R})$ with your weak topology would be the space of continuous functions of quadratic growth.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I overlook the obvious fact that for any dual pair $(X,Y)$, it always holds that $(X,\sigma(X,Y))^*=Y$.